# Deep web data scraping with python in google colaboratory

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I have the code from an answer to another question of mine.

It can pull data in each page. So, my next problem is how to drag data in each dress like model's name, model's size ,and features.

More than that there are more than one model in each dress (for example BOHO BIRD Amore Wrap Dress have a 3 model who wearing size 10, 14, and 16 [for example](https://www.birdsnest.com.au/brands/boho-bird/73067-amore-wrap-dress).

```
    import json
        
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    cookies = {
        "ServerID": "1033",
        "__zlcmid": "10tjXhWpDJVkUQL",
    }
    
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                      "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def extract_info(bs: BeautifulSoup, tag: str, attr_value: str) -> list:
        return [i.text.strip() for i in bs.find_all(tag, {"itemprop": attr_value})]

    def extract_info(bs: BeautifulSoup, tag: str, attr_value: str) -> list:
        return [i.text.strip() for i in bs.find_all(tag, {"itemprop": attr_value})]
    
    all_pages = []
    for page in range(1, 29):
        print(f"{all_pages}\nFound: {len(all_pages)} dresses.")
    
        current_page = f"https://www.birdsnest.com.au/womens/dresses?page={page}"
        source = requests.get(current_page, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
    
        brand = extract_info(soup, tag="strong", attr_value="brand")
        name = extract_info(soup, tag="h2", attr_value="name")
        price = extract_info(soup, tag="span", attr_value="price")
    
        all_pages.extend(
            [
                {
                    "brand": b,
                    "name": n,
                    "price": p,
                } for b, n, p in zip(brand, name, price)
            ]
        )
    
    with open("all_the_dresses2.json", "w") as jf:
        json.dump(all_pages, jf, indent=4)
```

Comment: What exactly you want to *drag* out of that page?

Comment: I want to analyze about clothing features and body shapes women. So, all the needed data is part of model's body measurement (name, wearing size, height, bust, waist, hips ) and
dress's features  like  v neckline, Extended ruffle overlay sleeve, Wrap dress with ties, Draped front skirt, Semi fitted, Satin feel fabric with sheen, no stretch.
And, in each dress, there are multiple models with a diverse body shape so I want to drag all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that you want is being generated dynamically. So, you won't get it with `requests`. I suggest you use selenium for that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


link = 'https://www.birdsnest.com.au/brands/boho-bird/73067-amore-wrap-dress'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/../Downloads/../chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()
page_new = soup.find('div', class_='model-info clearfix')
results = page_new.find_all('p')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Output

```
Marnee usually wears a size 8.
                She is wearing a size 10 in this style.
              
Her height is 178 cm.

Show Marnee’s body measurements

Marnee’s body measurements are:
Bust 81 cm
Waist 64 cm
Hips 89 cm
```

```html
<div class="model-info-header">
              <p>
                <strong><span class="model-info__name">Marnee</span></strong> usually wears a size <strong><span class="model-info__standard-size">8</span></strong>.
                She is wearing a size <strong><span class="model-info__wears-size">10</span></strong> in this style.
              </p>
              <p class="model-info-header__height">Her height is <strong><span class="model-info__height">178 cm</span></strong>.</p>
              <p>
                <span class="js-model-info-more model-info__link model-info-header__more">Show <span class="model-info__name">Marnee</span>’s body measurements</span>
              </p>
            </div>
```

With `requests` you will miss all the data in BOLD which is what you want.

Comment: error {File "<ipython-input-6-060b67f90cd5>", line 11
    driver.close()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent}

Comment: @Jay Sorry, there was a copy paste error. Updated the answer.

Comment: No module named 'selenium' -- that means I need to install selenium package in my computer right

Comment: yes. Also have to set the path for `chromedriver.exe` which you will also have to download.

Comment: Okay. I can do the part that you guide me. Then, if I want all of dress in the website with these dataset. What should I do...

Comment: @Jay that should be a new question, my friend. If this question was answered, please accept it.

Comment: So, I need to create a new question.